# Is safe to pass session as parameter into inner function to avoid zombie sessions and pool overflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am fairly new to SQLAlchemy and I wonder what is a right style to write code with sessions and splitting sqlalchemy queries into couple functions and to avoid zombie sessions in case of any exception ( To avoid overflow pool and make server irresponsible)
So, my question is ok to in one function create session and pass into another as parameter and in inner just call flush and in outter commit with finnaly, is this safe way to do or there is better way ?
For example

```
class Fetcher(object):

    def main(self, name):
        try:
            session = Session()
            user = session.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.name.like(name)).first()
            if user and user.active:
                relatives = _fetch_relatives(session, user.id)
                user.active = utc_time()
                session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            session.rollback()
        finally:
            session.close()


    def _fetch_relatives(self, session, id):
        relatives = []
        try:
            for r in session.query(RelativesModel).filter(RelativesModel.relative_id == id).all():
                relatives.apped({'name': r.name, 'age': r.age})
                r.readed = utc_time()
                session.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            session.rollback()
        finally:
            session.close()
        return relatives
```

Answer (score 1):

the best approach is to have just one outermost transactional scope for an entire operation.   Where you demarcate this scope is often something dependent on how the application works and there's some thoughts on this [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#session-frequently-asked-questions).

for the example given, having just one outermost scope would probably look like this, seeing that your object is called a "fetcher" and I'd assume a typical use case in your application has to fetch more than one thing - it's best to keep the scope of transactions and sessions *outside* of the scope of objects that work with specific parts of the database:

```
class Fetcher(object):

    def main(self, session, name):
        user = session.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.name.like(name)).first()
        if user and user.active:
            relatives = _fetch_relatives(session, user.id)
            user.active = utc_time()

    def _fetch_relatives(self, session, id):
        relatives = []
        for r in session.query(RelativesModel).filter(RelativesModel.relative_id == id).all():
            relatives.apped({'name': r.name, 'age': r.age})
            r.readed = utc_time()
            session.flush()
        return relatives

def run_my_program():
    session = Session()
    try:
        f1 = Fetcher()
        f1.main(session, "somename")

        # work with other fetchers, etc.

        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()
```